# Get minimum number without a Math function

Tags: javascript, function

I need to get a minimum number without using Math.Min function.

The function I've written is quite voluminous, how can I shortened the code and make it more compact?

Feel free to offer other solutions!

Here is my code:

```
function getMin(a,b,c) {
    if (a > b) {
        if (b > c) {
            return c;
        } else {
            return b;
        }
    } else {
        if (a > c) {
            return c;
        } else {
            return a;
        }  
    }    
}
```

Comment: But the question is, why do you need so without `Math.min`? what is the use case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a nested conditional structure.

```js
function getMin(a, b, c) {
    return a > b
        ? b > c ? c : b
        : a > c ? c : a;
}

console.log(getMin(1, 2, 3));
console.log(getMin(1, 3, 2));
console.log(getMin(2, 1, 3));
console.log(getMin(2, 3, 1));
console.log(getMin(3, 1, 2));
console.log(getMin(3, 2, 1));
```

Comment: Yours is same logic as my answer but uses the ternary operation. +1. While I like ternary operations, IMO it makes reading hard for nested `if`s.

Answer (score 2):

You might use `reduce` method with any number of arguments:

```js
function getMin(...args) {
  return args.reduce((r, a) => r < a ? r : a, Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER)
}

console.log(getMin(-12, 45, 765))
console.log(getMin(-12, 45, 76, 5, 13, -123))
```

Or do the same using the oldschool `for` loop:

```js
function getMin() {
  var min = Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER;
  for (var i in arguments)
    if (min > arguments[i]) min = arguments[i];
  return min;
}

console.log(getMin(-12, 45, 765))
console.log(getMin(-12, 45, 76, 5, 13, -123))
```

Comment: if you already use the spread operator you could directly take the rest parameter instead and omit the arguments ... (feel free to rollback if you disagree)

Answer (score 0):

Similar to yours but more compact, you can merge that if statements:

```
function(a,b,c){
    if (a>b && a>c) return a;
    if (b>a && b>a) return b;
    if (c>a && c>b) return c;
    return a; // if they are equal
}
```

This doesn't scale well with more numbers. As I said, it is just compact version of yours.

Answer (score 0):

**Very Easy**

```
    function getMin(a,b,c) {
      var min = arguments[0];
       for (var i = 0, j = arguments.length; i < j; i++){
            if (arguments[i] < min) {
                 min = arguments[i];
             }
        }
      return min;
    }

getMin(12,3,5,0,-8)
```

[Demo](https://codepen.io/fatih-erol/pen/ZMWzZQ)

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do so (I have just shared two example)

Here is the working example:
https://codebrace.com/editor/b0884a856

i. Using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```
function getmin(numarray){ 
      return numarray.reduce((a, b) => ((a > b)?b:a));
}
```

ii. using [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

```
function getmin(numarray){
      return numarray.sort()[0];
}
```